# find common indices that satisfy 2 conditions in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indices

I have an array that is 2D and quite large(8000x6000).
There are two conditions that are been satisfied for the same array (cond1 and cond2) and i want to reconcile them, find the common indices that satisfy both conditions

```
F=rand(8000,6000);
ind1=find(F>0.5);ind1 stores indices that satisfy cond1
```

The second condition (cond2) is whether the indices satisfy a condition.

```
newF=zeros(8000,6000);
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:6000,1:8000);
newF(x+y>200)=1;
```

The new array newF has zero values when the new condition is not satisfied, while the value is one when the condition is satisfied.

I want to find the common indices for F and newF that satisfy both conditions.
When i tried to find the ind2(r,c)

```
 [r,c]=find(newF>0)
```

I could not reconcile the ind1 and r,c to find the common indices.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: the indices are stored in cond1. Thank you.

Comment: done! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply logical matrices, obtained by applying the conditions, [element wise](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) and then use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to find common rows and column subscripts. i.e.

```
[r, c] = find((F>0.5) .* (newF>0));    
% .* is also replaceable by &. Use whichever is faster
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Using the & is much faster in my case.